# Import the data

Tags: importing-exporting, nodes

I have excel sheet where in I want to import all data into my Drupal site so for this I am using feed module, so while importing the data only the text fields are importing its not importing the entity reference field to drupal site its retaining empty for all those please can anyone tell me why is this strange ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Entity Reference feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_feeds) module. If you want to have multiple value field separated by a comma or something then use [feed tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module

Comment: I used entity reference feeds its not taking proper value

Comment: @shabir....I used the entity reference module but data are wrong for every entity reference field it considering only single value and if I use feed tamper it says Unknown data property Temporary target 1.

Comment: the other way I recently come across is to input your data through some php script and post it through services. You need services 3 module for that.

Comment: I don't know tat much coding , what exactly I need to do can you be more specific it helps me a lot